# Line spacing in UITextView mess up with Text background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uitextview

I have a UITextView (custom one) that have some ranges of text with background (like you can see in the first image). The UITextView is not editable (editable = NO).

You can see it in http://cl.ly/image/432A2Z3r0a0u

Now, if i want to change the line spacing, lets say 33 pts:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 33;
[textAttributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [textAttributedString length])];
```

then the Background is mess up http://cl.ly/image/1E33240h0f0V, The main idea is that the background color do not grow with the line height.

Comment: Add highlight color,  [attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor redColor]
                             range:selectedTextRange];

Comment: I'm actually doing that. the problem is that these background color grow in height as the line spacing grow.